# how to store data in a SQL server using classes in C#

Tags: asp.net, orm

I am a newbiew to aspn.et.My requirement is to create a simple class and web form. the data submitted to the form should be stored in object of the class and then it should be saved in the sql server database.Same way the retireval. thanks.

class Student
{
    int rollno;String name;int age;//default getters and settters
}

//web form has 3 text boxes for the above data fields.
//DB has a single table with these 3 fields

Comment: Can you post what you already have?

Comment: Are there any restrictions, such as inability to use Entity Framework?

Comment: no restriction of using entity framework. its just that i don't know how to use it. could you please help me with the steps to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the tutorials on asp.net, which covers pretty much all of the web technologies used/integrated with Visual Studio product.  Here is the link to the WebForms with Entity Framework that will walk you through how to do it.

http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/model-binding/retrieving-data

edit: Database first method -> http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/getting-started-with-ef/the-entity-framework-and-aspnet-getting-started-part-1

Additionally, if that tutorial doesn't suit your fancy, try this search: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=web-forms+database+first

Comment: thanks. that tutorial pretty much covers everything required. But, it Creates the database with the code. is there any alternative, that we have database created first and then use the ef to do DML operations!

Comment: thnaks friend. this is exactly what i needed. i will learn and practise.